# Ember’s contentSecurityPolicy

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have set this in my config

```
ENV['contentSecurityPolicy'] = {
  'connect-src': "'self' http://10.0.1.3:8000"
};
```

but seams to be entirely ignored. Am I doing something wrong? The goal would be to send the ajax calls to that ip, or localhost. Tried that one too, same result.

Answer (score 0):

@joseperales answered my question on GitHub issues (https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4960#issuecomment-149026102), so I am reposting it here so that it comes up in people’s searches.

```
'connect-src': "'self' http://10.0.1.3 http://10.0.1.3:8000"
```